# Is it possible to customize username field from the registration page in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to customize username field from the woocommerce registration page. My requirement is as per below.

```
1) User can enter only digits.

2) Length of username must be fixed 10.

3) Customize validation message.

4) Rename title of the username field on registration page.
```

For login page

```
1) Rename title of username field.
```

I searched for that but every time I got that how to add new custom field to the registration form but not getting any thing that how to customize existing field so I have doubt that is that possible to customize username field? If yes then how? I am new to wordpress and woocommerce so please help me

Yes, above things are possible by changes core file of woocommerce which I already did for now but I need to make those changes using `functions.php` file of `child theme` so it will not be affected when I update my woocommerce plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look inside the woocommerce plugin folder.
You will find templates for everything.
Make a folder called "woocommerce" in your theme folder and copy the folder myaccount to the "woocommerce" folder.
The folder contains a php file called `form-login.php`.
You can edit that file for required changes

Comment: Can I make that `woocommerce` folder in my `child-theme` folder? So when I update my main theme, changes can work as it is

Comment: I think that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Yes it's working but I can only rename the title of the field by editing `form-login.php` file. How can I restrict that field so user can enter only digits of fixed length? For now I have updated `wp-includes/user.php` for that restriction and to change validation message I have updated `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-user-functions.php`

Comment: I would suggest not editing the plugin files directly as the edits might be replaced during update. As per the restrictions, you can put restrictions on the input field by changing its type to number and adding min and max parameters to it

Comment: As for the validation message, I'm sure there's a hook for that. A few minutes in Google or looking at what filters have been applied in the include files will let you figure out the hook